# how to insert data into a loyalty card and save as jpg or png format in php

Tags: php, laravel

Suppose I have some loyalty card samples(like `.jpg` or `.png` format) in my Laravel website.

[image: Loyalty Card Sample]

To achieve any loyalty card, user need to fill up some info field like `username`, `mobile number`, `email`. After filing the information user choose any loyalty card sample and click submit.
Then an unique number generate and a new loyalty card will be shown with all user information(in `.jpg` or `.png` format) that he given.

So my question is How can I save data upon a `.jpg` or `.png` image using PHP or Laravel?

Anybody can help please ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a lot of options, of varying complexity.

Comment: maybe create html,css versions of these card designs, dynamically fill in names n stuff and then use [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) js library to save it as an image file

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would imagine php [has some image functions that can "open" an existing image and add text to it at a given position](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php)